# Is there any documentation on the package.json file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Here's an instance of the *package.json* file that express.js generates

```
{
    "name": "packagename",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "2.5.5",
        "stylus": "0.22.2"
    }
}
```

It's fairly obvious that I can add packages to the dependencies object. However I have no idea what `"private": true` means. Nor do I know what syntax I can use in the dependencies value fields. I've Googled for quite a while without discovering anything.

What I'm wondering is pretty much if a complete summary of all settings that the *package.json* file can contain exists, as I could not find one. I haven't checked `man` since I'm on a windows PC.

Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You're looking for the output of `npm help json`. It is available in Markdown format [on NPM's GitHub project](https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/latest/docs/lib/content/configuring-npm/package-json.md#files).

Also check out [this interactive guide](http://browsenpm.org/package.json):

[image: SShot]

Answer (score 25):

Besides the [official guide for package.json from NPM](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/configuring-npm/package-json), the guys from Nodejitsu made a nice cheatsheet for it: http://package.json.nodejitsu.com/

Answer (score 1):

I've found this very useful...

https://npmjs.org/doc/json.html

Answer (score 1):

A [package.json cheatsheet](http://browsenpm.org/package.json). The most beautiful documentation that I could find for package.json.